# Reactjs - passing two states with props

Tags: reactjs, properties, parameter-passing, react-props

I have an object in React which I am iterating over, I would like to add two value from my state (users and details), is it possible to combine like this?

```
 {
    Object
    .keys(this.state.users)
    .map(key => <UsersTable key={key} 
    users={this.state.users[key]} details={this.state.details[key]} />)
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error, this seems to be a correct implementation

Comment: May be you will be get scope issues..Sometimes 'this' will become undefined inside map().  So declare 'this' to a variable outside and use that

Comment: @Jayabalaji don't arrow functions bind the scope on your behalf?

Comment: I am getting a not found error which let me to believe the 'this' was the wrong scope BUT it is an arrow function.

Comment: @fshock Yes it does automatically bind scope.  But i have faced this issue sometimes even after using arrow functions.  Just wanna give a try:-)